# What if x and x2 values are same in X range highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am using a x range chart in Highcharts.

I have dates in x axis. One of the data have both x and x2 same values. Means start and end date is same.

How will that be visible in the chart?

Answer (score 0):

I think something that starts and ends exactly at one point in time is not good to represent in the x-range series. Here it is necessary to specify the exact duration. You can do this by adjusting your data accordingly, e.g. using Date.UTC (): https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9pjw0m8b/

```
data: [{
      x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 1, 0),
      x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 1, 1),
      y: 0
    }]
```

Comment: That was useful. I tried with time and now able to find the chart plotting.

Comment: Good to hear that! Could you please mark this answer then? Thanks in advance!